# Capital R with whitespace padding

Tags: spacing, symbols, characters, syntax

I'm a math and latex novice, and I'm trying to write out the following rule with latex:

[image]

I'm having a hard time with this capital R. In the textbook, it has that nice side padding but when I type something like `x R y`, it's all squashed together.

As for the cancelled syntax, `x \cancel{R} y` seems to do the trick, but I'm not sure if that's the right way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a new symbol enclosed in `\mathrel`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\rel}{\mathrel{R}}

\begin{document}

$a\rel b\not\rel c$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because math mode gobbles whitespace.  In order to get nice spacing you have to use one of a series of whitespace commands, like `\;`

[This image gives you all of them](https://pics.latexstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/whitespace-latex-math-mode.png), but for this formula try (using two dollar signs centres a formula and puts it on it's own line):

```
\[x R y\]
\[x\;R\;y\]
```

This renders as:

[image]

(thanks to Sandy G for the edits)

Comment: In LaTeX you should always use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`. [Explanation here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/125871). Also, for a relation you should use `\;` to imitate the spacing. The command `\:` produces the (slightly smaller) spacing used for binary operations like `+`.